# Getting Error "type object 'User' has no attribute 'POST' " while login authentication while fetching data from Mysql database

Tags: mysql, django-models, django-authentication

> I am stuck here from past 2days. It worked fine when first time I created "createsuperuser" command and I next I modified code by authenticating only Email and Password without username. Again I created newdatabase in  Mysql and created "superuser". I also created Regestration method with Posts data into database it is working fine. But when I fetch data(Loin Authentication) it is throwing error. And I dont have any Form models in my App.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from django.contrib import messages


def view_comein(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    username = User.POST['username']
    # it is not executing here
    password = User.POST['password']

    user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password = password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.loginPage(user)
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        messages.info(request, 'Invalied Credentials')
        return redirect('loginPage')


 else:
     return render(request, 'loginPage.html')
```

[Error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjTpY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look closely below code. You are accessing invalid attribute.

```
def view_comein(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username'] #**request; not User**
        # it is not executing here
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password = password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user) #auth.login; not auth.loginPage
```